# c# Case switch method in a class

Tags: c#, class, methods, switch-statement, case

Trying to have a method inside a class and I'm having trouble setting it up. Trying to set up a string `appstatus` method that saves the string to `appstatus` but first must set the value to it. I want to ultimately set values to `appstatus` from a sql query and access them later inside my list

```
public class SampleData
{
public SampleData()
{
}
public string name { get; set; }
public string phoneNbr { get; set; }
public string appstatus 
 { 
 get
 {
   return appstatus;
 }
  set
  {
    switch (appstatus)
    {
        case "A":
            appstatus= "Yes";
            break;
        case "B":
            appstatus= "No";
            break;
        case "E":
            appstatus= "Need More Info";
            break;
        default:
            appstatus= ("Unknown");
            break;
    }
 }
}

...using (SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (read.Read())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        SampleData d1 = new SampleData();
                        d1.name = Convert.ToString(read["..."]);
                        d1.phoneNbr = Convert.ToString(read["..."]);                            
                        d1.appstatus = (Convert.ToString(read["..."]).Trim());

                        list.Add(d1);
                    }
            }
     }
```

Comment: Do you have a problem?

Comment: You need a backing field.

Comment: You can access the object you saved in the list using List[index] where index is a numeric value indicating the position the object was saved in.

Comment: This code will recursively call the appstatus, try refactoring your code. The better approach could be using Dictionary<string,string> where you could map your strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `switch` statement needs to use *`value`* and not `appstatus`.  Because `appstatus` is not an auto implemented property, you also need to store the value in a private member and change the `get` to return that value.

```
 private string _appstatus;
 public string appstatus 
 { 
 get
 {
   return _appstatus;
 }
  set
  {
    switch (value)
    {
        case "A":
            _appstatus= "Yes";
            break;
        case "B":
            _appstatus= "No";
            break;
        case "E":
            _appstatus= "Need More Info";
            break;
        default:
            _appstatus= "Unknown";
            break;
    }
 }
```

Comment: You've silently corrected an error, too; might want to mention it.

Comment: Also I suggest making your appstatus an enumeration

Answer (score 0):

You Setter is calling it self recursively and will throw exception.

My suggestion would be :

```
public class SampleData
{
    public SampleData(string name, string phoneNbr, string appStatus)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.phoneNbr = phoneNbr;
        this.appstatus = appstatus;
    }

    public string name { get; private set; }
    public string phoneNbr { get; private set; }

    public string appstatus {  get; private set;  }
```

And now in the other code you can use it this way

```
try
{
    SampleData d1 = new SampleData(
                         Convert.ToString(read["..."]),
                         Convert.ToString(read["..."]),
                         Convert.ToString(read["..."]).Trim());
    list.Add(d1);
```